# KeyCode === 13 having trouble with the dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

Here is a Bin = http://jsbin.com/ekasuv/1/edit

code I am using is this:

```
  $('#pop_up').on('keyup','.textual',function(event){
          var did= $(this).attr('data-id');
      if(did ==="titles_sendto"){
          var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);   
      if(keycode === '13') {
          var AuthSendUser = $(this).val();
       $('#ListedAuthSend').append('<li>'+ AuthSendUser +'</li>');
       $(this).val(" ");
     }
   }
});
```

Though everytime I press enter it does not pass the code. Now maybe I am overlooking something or just forgetting something. though I am tired, and need some of S.O assistance. Can someone take a glance and see what I may be doing wrong.

I've also tried `.on('focus',`

Comment: statement fails because `'13`' is a string, and keycode is returning an int, simply use `13`, or `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#pop_up').on('keyup','.textual',function(e){
   var did= $(this).attr('data-id');
   if(did == "titles_sendto" && e.which == 13){
       $('#ListedAuthSend').append('<li>'+ this.value +'</li>');
       this.value = '';
   }
});
```

[**BIN**](http://jsbin.com/ekasuv/2/)

Comment: See what I mean! Silly silly me. I knew I was completely overlooking something. I was wondering. Thank you Adeneo, I believe you helped me on another project before. I really appreciate your help, I wish I could just tag you for now on ;) lol

Comment: I'll accept in 6 minutes ok. I may have another problem with the entire code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827249/creating-multiple-elements-based-of-length please help with this

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, your code doesn't pass the if statement when you press enter? This works for me:

```
if(keycode == '13'){
  alert('passed');
}
```

just use two `=` sign and it works fine. Here's your edited **[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ekasuv/5/edit)**.