# Creating multiple elements based of .length

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

Ok so here is a basic markup

```
<ul>
    <li>User 1</li>
    <li>User 2</li>
    <li>User 3</li>
</ul>
<form>
    <input type="text" value="" name="username[]" id="users"/>
</form>
```

What I want to do is get the length of the ul, which I know how to do, so if the number is 3 it will create 3 `<input type="text" name="username[]" value="" id="users"/>` With the Username that is in the Li in that element so basically after a user presses a button the form should then look like this

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="User 1" name="username[]" id="users"/>
    <input type="text" value="User 2" name="username[]" id="users"/>
    <input type="text" value="User 3" name="username[]" id="users"/>
</form>
```

So of the coding I have now is

```
$('#form_submit').click(function() {
    var id="#"+ $('.dataSrc').attr('data-id');
    if(id =="#titles_sendto" && $('#ListedAuthSend li').length >= 1) {
        var ListAuthUsers = [];
        var listedAuthUsers = $('#ListedAuthSend li');

        for(var i =0;i<listedAuthUsers.length;i++){
            var name = $(listedAuthUsers[i]).text();
            ListAuthUsers.push(name);
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ibebax/1/edit   visually see the code

Would something like this work?

```
for(var j=0;j<ListAuthUsers.length;j++){
 var tab = $(ListAuthUsers[i]);
 var html = '<ul>';
 html += '<li>'+tab+'</li>';
 alert(html);
 }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Basically get the length of how many LIs are in the UL. the above is three. so if there is three, add three of the elements I said, with each value being the corresponding name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this inside the loop to create the inputs:

```
var input = $("<input type='text'>");
input.attr("id", "users" + i);
input.attr("name", "username[" + i + "]");
input.val($(listedAuthors[i]).text());
input.appendTo(formsubmit);
```

in action: http://jsfiddle.net/tbLmQ/1/

Comment: works great man. Atleast someone understood what I meant ;) I know it was hard to explain. that was my bad. Thank you though and it works fabulously!

Comment: You beat me to the fiddle! :P

Comment: lol ^^^ I just liked his method better, plus yours just adds the elements, not the value. thanks though David I upvoted you though

Answer (score 3):

Put something like this inside your for loop:

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'username[]',
    id: 'users'
}).appendTo('form');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way.

Ids must be unique, unlike your example, so this will handle creation of unique id.

```
var inputTemplate = $('<input type="text"  name="username[]" />'); //Create a template for the input

$('#form_submit').click(function () {
    var inputs = $('#ListedAuthSend li').map(function (i, ob) {//Use $.map to convert the li's to input.
        return inputTemplate.clone()
               .val(this.innerHTML)
               .attr('id', 'users' + i);
    }).get();

    $('form').html(inputs); //paste it in form.
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KKZjC/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery.map:

```
$('#form_submit').click(function() {
   var $list_auth_users = $('#ListedAuthSend li'),
       input = $('<input type="text" name="username[]"></input>')
   ;

   $('form').html(
     $list_auth_users.map(function(index, user){
       var name = $(user).text();
       return input.clone()
         .attr('id', 'user_' + index)
         .attr('value', name);
     }).get()
   );
});
```

Link here: http://jsbin.com/ibebax/3/edit

---

or for loop

```
$('#form_submit').click(function() {
   var $users = $('#ListedAuthSend li'),
       input = $('<input type="text" name="username[]"></input>'),
       form_list = [],
       name
   ;


   for (var index = 0; index < $users.length; index++) {
      name = $($users[index]).text();
      $(input.clone().attr('id', 'user_' + index).attr('value', name))
          .appendTo('form'); 
   }
});
```

Link here: http://jsbin.com/ibebax/10/edit

---

For future reference, you cannot have multiple elements with the same *id*, but you can with the same *class*

wrong:

```
<div id="f"></div>
<div id="f"></div>
```

right:

```
<div id="a" class="f"></div>
<div id="b" class="f"></div>
```

Comment: I know about IDs, I just copied the HTML of the form I am manipulating which had the ID.

Comment: ah, ok. just thought i'd mention it for anybody else who comes along

Comment: Well very good :D Yes this is true, as I've seen some errors like this on my own tutorial site. They don't understand why a click event is not working for all elements, though the click function is on an ID that is not unique, so its easy, change it to class :D lol

Answer (score 0):

You may like this

```
$('#form_submit').click(function() {
    $('form').empty();
    $('#ListedAuthSend li').each(function(k, v){
        var txt = $('<input>',{'name':'username[]','id':'users','value':$(v).text() });
        $('form').append(txt);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3KnvX/1/)

**Update:** using `for` loop

```
$('#form_submit').click(function() {
    $('form').empty();
    var lis = $('#ListedAuthSend li');
    for(var i=0; i<lis.length;i++){
        var txt = $('<input>',{'name':'username[]','id':'users','value':$(lis[i]).text() });
        $('form').append(txt);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3KnvX/2/)

Comment: no, since you use the .each() which if you look at my comment on undefineds answer, I don't ever use that from jQuery. There are a few things I won't use, and would rather use the JavaScript way instead

Comment: Thank you for the update Sheikh, more users should try and stray away from the .each() especially if they say the Dev version of jQuery 1.9 and the .each() function, which contains a for loop plus more. which is unneeded a lot of the times

Comment: @EasyBB, `jQuery` is a wrapper on `JavaScript` so in every case it's same but it simplifies the task.

Comment: Yes I know this, but I wouldn't want my code searching so much jQuery when javascript is right there in hand